# Array to string conversion while using implode() PHP

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am trying to do

```
echo implode(" ", $problem);
```

but when I do I get an Array to string conversion error. The weird part is that it works but it still gives me an error. The print_r reads

```
( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Password must be at least 8 characters [2] => Password must have at least one special character )
```

Comment: The first element in the array is also an array!

Comment: maybe `array_filter` it...  Unless there might be non-empty arrays in it.